# Check hierarchically for parent number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Table that I am using is `CADIGR`, and column `DIGR_KEY1` is always a parent number (`DIGR_KEY` of the parent) in the row.

I must update `CADIGR DIGR_KEY1` (parent number), but first I must check that I am not updating child with one of theirs parent.

I really don't have idea how to do this? Child can have a lot of parents, so check must be done on the whole tree up to the root (where `DIGR_KEY1 IS NULL`).

Only if the number does not exist as parent number of that child's tree, update is possible.

```
CREATE TABLE CADIGR
(
DIGR_KEY INT,
DIGR_KEY1 INT
)


INSERT INTO CADIGR (DIGR_KEY, DIGR_KEY1)
VALUES
(1, NULL),
(2,1),
(3,1),
(4,1),
(11,4),
(12,4),
(13,4),
(5,2),
(6,2),
(5,2),
(6,2),
(7,5),
(8,5),
(9,5),
(10,5),
(14,3),
(15,3)
```

Comment: You can use a [Recursive Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Thank you Magnus. Do you also have any example?

Comment: You don't need a CTE, SQL Server already has a `hierarchyid` type that can be used to define accelerate hierarchical relations and searches

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - perhaps you have any example on this? This sounds really interesting.

Comment: SQL Server's documentation has an entire chapter on this, including how to convert parent-child relations to hierarchyid, how to add/remove/change relations etc. Check [Hierarchical Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/hierarchical-data-sql-server) and [Tutorial: Using the hierarchyid Data Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/tutorial-using-the-hierarchyid-data-type) for starters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive query like this, can use level to perform operations on each group of childs.

> ```
> WITH Rec as
> (
>     SELECT digr_key, digr_key1, 1 AS level
>     FROM   CADIGR
>     WHERE  digr_key1 is null
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT     c.digr_key, c.digr_key1, level = level + 1
>     FROM       CADIGR c
>     INNER JOIN rec
>     ON         c.digr_key1 = rec.digr_key
> )
> SELECT *
> FROM   Rec;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> digr_key | digr_key1 | level
> -------: | --------: | ----:
>        1 |      null |     1
>        2 |         1 |     2
>        3 |         1 |     2
>        4 |         1 |     2
>       11 |         4 |     3
>       12 |         4 |     3
>       13 |         4 |     3
>       14 |         3 |     3
>       15 |         3 |     3
>        5 |         2 |     3
>        6 |         2 |     3
>        5 |         2 |     3
>        6 |         2 |     3
>        7 |         5 |     4
>        8 |         5 |     4
>        9 |         5 |     4
>       10 |         5 |     4
>        7 |         5 |     4
>        8 |         5 |     4
>        9 |         5 |     4
>       10 |         5 |     4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=86ddcf9b26c1052c6e51ffb4572e30ea)*

**Avoiding duplicated records**

> ```
> WITH DistData as
> (
>     SELECT DISTINCT digr_key, digr_key1
>     FROM   CADIGR
> )
>     , Rec as
>     (
>         SELECT digr_key, digr_key1, 1 AS level
>         FROM   DistData
>         WHERE  digr_key1 is null
>         UNION ALL
>         SELECT     c.digr_key, c.digr_key1, level = level + 1
>         FROM       DistData c
>         INNER JOIN rec
>         ON         c.digr_key1 = rec.digr_key
>     )
>     SELECT *
>     FROM   Rec;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> digr_key | digr_key1 | level
> -------: | --------: | ----:
>        1 |      null |     1
>        2 |         1 |     2
>        3 |         1 |     2
>        4 |         1 |     2
>       11 |         4 |     3
>       12 |         4 |     3
>       13 |         4 |     3
>       14 |         3 |     3
>       15 |         3 |     3
>        5 |         2 |     3
>        6 |         2 |     3
>        7 |         5 |     4
>        8 |         5 |     4
>        9 |         5 |     4
>       10 |         5 |     4
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2eb54fb4b23931421a2537b060d786e3)*

Comment: SQL Server supports hierarchical structures and searches throuth hierarchyid. The performance is orders of magnitude better than CTEs

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos sure, but the OP table schema is this.

Comment: @McNets - why is DIGR_KEY1 = 5 doubling? (7,5),(8,5),(9,5),(10,5) are doubled.

Comment: @McNets the schema can change. The performance of the CTE though can't be improved

Comment: @FrenkyB you have duplicate records, must be avoided?

Comment: @McNets - well, not necessarilly. Good to avoid, but it's not necessary.

Comment: To avoid duplicates: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2eb54fb4b23931421a2537b060d786e3